# Thread in .NET Function never returns

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I'm currently working on a legacy .NET 4.7 project. I am calling a method, that starts a Thread with an infinite while loop. My problem is, ReSharper indicates, that the "function never returns".

The program logic works fine, and I haven't had any errors yet.

The code looks like this:

```
private void StartThread(Action action, int timeout)
{
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Warn($"Exception sending {action.Method.Name}.", ex);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        }
    }) // ReSharper indicates here, that the function never returns, though it's void...
    {
        Name = $"TestThread1",
        IsBackground = true
    }.Start();
}
```

What do you think, is the code actually working fine and should I forget about the ReSharper warning?

Or, how could I improve my coding?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I would read it as "the anonymous function that you're running in that thread will never return" - and that's true. And by design. The method `StartSendingThread` will return. Note that it doesn't matter what the return type is - even `void` returning methods return (usually).

Answer (score 2):

With "never returns" the compiler means "never ends". A function can fully return, despite it's return value being of the (non-)type void.

Literally the first thing you put in was a infinite loop. 
The 2nd thing is a Try Block that catches all exceptions. Short of the Thread.Abort() mechanic when you target the .NET Framework or the OS, nothing is going to kill this.

Infinite loops are just always a bad idea. Usually loops check for failure conditions. Stuff like "user elected to close the application, stop running that Event Queue". Often the loop ending is how the function or even teh whole application end. That EventQueue is literally keeping those Windows Forms applications alife.

Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and that catch block has to be fixed. You also need to go out of your way to make sure that Exceptions are not accidentally swallowed by the thread. Multithreading is well known for that behavior. There are [two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) [articles](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET) on the mater I link often. The only reason to catch exception, is to make sure this error is persisted when the thread ends or logged - and then throw on.

The actuall Multithreading code could use bool value other code can set. It also depends on what action does, if further steps (like race condition prevention) have to be taken.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a WaitHandle. Because, `while (true)` will trash the CPU performance, it will take as much as possible from CPU power. `Thread.Sleep(timeout)` refuses the remainder of the current time-slice but it still leads to a high level of CPU utilization.

To avoid the infinity loop use EventWaitHandle:

```
var waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "0597f0b8-4472-4e60-b56f-bb44c4ded684", out var createdNew);

    private void StartThread(Action action, int timeout, EventWaitHandle waitHandle)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var signaled = false;
            do
            {
                //Your code

                // Wait until someone tells us to stop or do something else
                signaled = waitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
            } while (!signaled);

        })
        {
            IsBackground = true
        }.Start();
    }
```